# Change next hub on Comcast modem

Tags: networking, routing, windows-networking, network-protocols

I’m really curious about networking and I have a question.

Assuming that my ISP is Comcast , my modem will forward my traffic through its public address and if the host that I’m asking for it’s outside Comcast Autonomous System, then the edge router at Comcast will be an specific one determined by their Interior Gateway protocol that they use , but I think today I learned at school that BGP which is an Exterior Gateway protocol can specify that if traffic in order to get back to the original Autonomous System can take another route (even if this one its not preferred) it will take this different route if specify by BGP (I believe this can be specify by The MED on the BGP route selection process) .

Because of this I could assume that each Comcast edge router that connects Comcast network with other networks has a backup route or a less preferred route’ but if asked for it will take certain traffic to that second route which could be longer or less preferred some how.

Question 1:: How could I verify that from my PC ?

Question 2 :: Can I route traffic from my pc and determine which route it will take to get to its destination through the Comcast network? It will be really cool , if From Florida I could ask Comcast to route me through San Francisco and traffic be transferred back through a different route.

Question 3 :: Can this be down scale to the point where I could request to any router ( my Comcast modem for example ) to forward my traffic through a different next hop than the one that it will send it to?

I’m starting on networking please be kind with me.

Comment: Do you have an actual computer hardware or software question. As it stands this question will most likely be closed, it seems to be off-topic for this forum.

Comment: I’ll close this topic

Comment: How can I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1:: How could I verify that from my PC ?

You cannot, without access to the router to verify it's configuration and routing tables.

> Question 2 :: Can I route traffic from my pc and determine which route it will take to get to its destination through the Comcast network? It will be really cool , if From Florida I could ask Comcast to route me through San Francisco and traffic be transferred back through a different route.

You cannot ask Comcast (or any other network) to route your traffic in any specific way. They will chose what they consider to be the best path.

> Question 3 :: Can this be down scale to the point where I could request to any router ( my Comcast modem for example ) to forward my traffic through a different next hop than the one that it will send it to?

No. You do not have any control over how packets are routed on the internet by other devices and other networks.

Think about this for a while. Networks would lose all control over their networks, their stability and performance if clients were to decide how they would need to route packets. Capacity planning would be impossible, as would be traffic engineering or doing maintenance on specific links. The bottomline of how the internet works: every network has a little (but not much) influence on incoming traffic, but it's up to each network to decide what their outbound routing policy is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the way they explained it to me sounded that you could , it didn’t make sense to me ether and that’s why I asked the question. Thank you.